# How to separate each declared string in another string by comma in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC. I want to separate each declared string in another string by using comma and without using an array. And I need to pass that comma separated string in another Java file. 
here is my code:
below is the model having three different setters and getters

```
public String pk1=getInstitutionId();
public String pk2=getInstitutionName();
public String pk3=getIsoCountryCode();
```

And Now I want to split this by using comma like this:

```
private String MultipleprimaryKeyStr= pk1 + "," + pk2 + "," + pk3;
```

But this pk1, pk2 and pk3 are taking as separate string. But MultipleprimaryKeyStr should take it as variable.

Comment: your question is confusing. What you want to do? Want to split or want to concate?

Comment: I want to split.
like this:
String [] params = paramsCSV.split(",");
But not by using an array.

Comment: I think you could be. Can you share both method´s code here?

Comment: If you want to split MultipleprimaryKeyStr you could do :
`MultipleprimaryKeyStr.split(",');`
After that you have an Array of Strings with the values.

Comment: public void authorizerApprove(String key, String[] params) {
  Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  /*Get id of the record that is approved*/
  String MultiplePrimaryKeyStr=(params[0],params[1],params[]);
  /*Mark this record as approved by the authorizer*/
  MakerCheckerDao makerCheckerDao = (MakerCheckerDao) classProvider.getClassByName(
    viewToClassMapper.getMakerCheckerDaoClassName(key));
  makerCheckerDao.authorizerApprove(MultiplePrimaryKeyStr, auth.getName(), params[1]);

Comment: Above is the code in which I want to that string MultiplePrimaryKeyStr as params[0],params[1],params[2]

Comment: If I use array, I m getting stuck at this line :
MultiplePrimaryKeyStr = (params[0],params[1],params[2]);
This is showing error.

Comment: You have to do like String MultipleprimaryKeyStr= params[0] + "," + params[1] + "," + params[2];

Comment: @rucha, Please.... don't post large blocks of code in comments. Add it to your existing question post instead. :/

Comment: @RajnikantPatel: Thank you sir. U gave me the solution.

Comment: @DevilsHnd: Sorry sir!! Yes sir you are right. I can do that also.

Comment: @DevilsHnd: I want to accept your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do like

```
String MultipleprimaryKeyStr= params[0] + "," + params[1] + "," + params[2];
```

One more thing, I would like to tell you that you should not go in static but you should run while or for loop there like this:

```
String MultiplePrimaryKeyStr = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
    {
        MultiplePrimaryKeyStr = ((i!=0) ? "," : "") + params[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing `pk1 + "," + pk2 + "," + pk3` you are creating a new String because the operator + is used for concatenation operation in Strings.
So now you get this new String and you can split this String using `split(",")` as:

```
private String MultipleprimaryKeyStr= pk1 + "," + pk2 + "," + pk3;
String[] newStr= MultipleprimaryKeyStr.split(",");
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this code also. But I have to pass this into another Java file which is like this:
public void authorizerApprove( String[] params)
String[] primaryKeyStr = (params[0],params[1],params[2]);
These two lines are not valid.
how to do this?

Comment: i am not able to get your comment, could you please tell it more clearly

Comment: MultipleprimaryKeyStr= params[0] + "," + params[1] + "," + params[2]; 

I can do like this also. Right?

Comment: Yes you can do it like this, i think this is the right way

Comment: You just simply do: `String MultipleprimaryKeyStr = params[0] + "," + params[1] + "," + params[2];`

Comment: Thank you sir.
It was little bit easy. I didnt put my brain.

Answer (score 0):

By doing concatenation of multiple string into one string and those string is separated by comma. 
Ex. String MultiplePrimaryKeyStr="This, is, separated, string";

just pass this string to new java file. And split in that file by calling split().

String[] sepratedString=MultiplePrimaryKeyStr.split(",");
process that string array inside loop.

Comment: Thank you for your approach!! But I dont want to use array in another file.
In another file, I want like this which is not possible.
`String [] MultipleprimaryKeyStr = params[0], params[1], params[2];`